# The {0} ok prompt is missing a # inside the {}

Tags: solaris, sun, prompt

We have tried to replicate at our lab facility but were unable to get empty braces {}. We tried with hard drives in place and with none. There is also no errors indicated when using the rotary switch in the diag position. What does the number inside the braces mean {0} ok, {1} ok?

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the SPARC OpenBoot PROM prompt, [the number inside the braces refers to which CPU is in use](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63648_01/html/E63649/gpsgy.html#scrolltoc) on a multi-CPU system.

If you're referring to some other prompt, you'll need to state what/where it is.